# Custom pattern matching in Swift 2.2 not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Following the excellent blog post here: https://appventure.me/2015/08/20/swift-pattern-matching-in-detail/#sec-3-7 I've tried custom pattern matching. Let's define an `enum` representing two kinds of strings:

```
enum LineType : String {
    case Event = "event:"
    case Data = "data:"
}
```

Next, a `String` extension capable of telling if a string starts with one or the other value of the `LineType`:

```
extension String {
    func isOfType(type: LineType) -> Bool {
        return self.hasPrefix(type.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Then the custom pattern matching function, checking if a string is of a given type:

```
func ~= (pattern: LineType, value: String) -> Bool {
    return value.isOfType(pattern)
}
```

Finally, let's test it with this example:

```
let testLine = "event:yada-yada-yada"

switch testLine {
case _ where testLine.characters.count == 0:
    print("Empty")
case LineType.Event: // <--- Causes the error Enum case 'Event' is not a member of type 'String'
    print("Event")
case LineType.Data: // <--- Causes the error Enum case 'Data' is not a member of type 'String'
    print("Data")
default:
    print("Unknown Type")
}
```

So if someone can tell me what I do wrong...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, it fails to compile if the pattern is an enumeration type.

Comment: @MartinR case { LineType.Event }(): print("Event") solve the trouble ... or better define constants let e = LineType.Event; ... case e: ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch testLine {
case _ where testLine.characters.count == 0:
    print("Empty")
case _ where testLine.isOfType(.Event): print("Event")
case _ where testLine.isOfType(.Data):  print("Data")
default: print("Unknown Type")
}

/* prints
 Event
 */
```

still, try to rearrange it ...

it looks terrible, but this works, as expected

```
enum LineType : String {
    case Event = "event:"
    case Data = "data:"
}
func ~= (pattern: LineType, value: String) -> Bool {
    return value.hasPrefix(pattern.rawValue)
}


let testLine = "event:yada-yada-yada"
let e = LineType.Event
let d = LineType.Data
switch testLine {
case let s where s.characters.count == 0: print("Empty")
case e: print("Event")
case d: print("Data")
default: print("Unknown Type")
}
/* prints
 Event
 */
```

this should also work

```
...
case { return LineType.Event }(): print("Event")
...
```

or

```
...
case { LineType.Event }(): print("Event")
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I try to avoid. Because it's not custom pattern matching. The principle of custom pattern matching is to call the `~=` function in the `switch case` not writing it each time. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Zaphod see my update, even though i don't see any advantage of using custom operator there

Comment: In fact the `~=` operator is the one involved in the `switch case` pattern matching. You should not need to write it. Take a look at the link at the start of the question.

Comment: @Zaphod let think about as a workaround. your question is valid and i confirm the same behavior as you have (XCode 7.3)

Comment: @Zaphod it seems, that the trouble is that enum can not be initialized. assigning enum to constants solve the trouble ... see my update

Answer (score 0):

Yep, no solution other than to use `.rawValue`. But you already know how to do that.

I tested this out in a playground (using Xcode 7.3), and I can confirm that this does not work. Adding `public` modifiers to the functions involved did not help either. I suggest filing a bug report at the [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com), or better yet, the [Swift Bug Reporter](https://bugs.swift.org) (as suggested by @OleBegemann).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The workaround with the { }() works but as the expected behavior does not, I'm going to report it to both platforms.

Comment: Apple bug report filed : #25485364 - Swift bug report : SR-1121